# How can I change the drive number

Tags: freebsd

I installed FreeBSD 8.1 on a machine where the drive was `/dev/ad6` but have moved it to a new system where the drive is now `/dev/ad4`. The new system boots but I need to manually specify that the root file system is on `ad4s1`.

How can I change the boot loader to do this automatically? Googling around turns up examples of `disklabel -e` being able to change the disk number, but I only get "Class not found" errors and no disk label changes with this method.

Comment: `/etc/disktab` and `bsdlabel -B`?  `/boot/kernel.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sysinstall` (`Configure > Label`) allowed fixing the disk label. One oddity was that the editor came up with the correct disk number (i.e. ad4), but selecting `W` wrote out the correct label and fixed the boot problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the following scenario:

I intalled FreeBSD 10.1 USB `.img` file to 1GB stick and installed FreeBSD to the 16GB stick. 1GB stick was recognized as `/dev/da0`, and the 16GB stick as `/dev/da1`. FreeBSD was installed to 16GB stick under `/dev/da1s2a`. Then I removed 1GB stick and—normally—cannot boot to FreeBSD system automatically. The system said that cannot boot to `vfs.root.mountfrom="/dev/da1s2a"`, but offered me to manually boot into FreeBSD, so I had to change the boot slice to `/dev/da0s2a`, and it worked. Off course, I don’t want to do it manually, so I found this post.

It inspired me to search for the location of variable `vfs.root.mountfrom`, so I remoot the system, pull out the 16GB stick, put back the 1GB stick, boot from it as a Live CD. At this point, I put back the 16GB stick, mounted it (`mount /dev/da1s2a /mnt`) and searched for "vfs.root.mountfrom". My findings were:

1. DO NOT CHANGE the `/boot/loader.conf` file!
2. DO NOT CHANGE the `/boot/defaults/loader.conf` file!

Since doing those things will mess up the loader!

The solution was to tweak the `/etc/fstab` on the `/mnt` (16GB stick) changing the entry `/dev/da1s2a` to `/dev/da0s2a/` as the loader is looking the `fstab` for file systems in `fstab` during booting and automatically write the value of the `vfs.Root.Mountfrom` variable!!!

So during reboot I removed the 1GB stick and the machine successfully booted up the FreeBSD!

Comment: I installed FreeBSD on an XServe then moved the origial disk out so the drive numbers changed (ata1 to ata0).  This simple solution fixed it instantly.

Answer (score 2):

The file /boot/loader.conf contains the instructions on which filesystem to mount as root.

Check this file for an enrty:

```
vfs.root.mountfrom="ufs:ad6s1a"
```

and tweak it (or add it if it's missing) to read:

```
vfs.root.mountfrom="ufs:ad4s1a"
```

(that is assuming partition a of slice 1 of device 4)

Comment: This was very simple, and worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change `/boot.config`.

See the [boot.config](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=boot.config&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE]) man page.

It suggests you want something like

```
echo "1:ad(4,a)/boot/loader" > /boot.config
```

But cat the file first to see what `/dev/ad6` is, then figure out what `/dev/ad4` should be.